# Pseudoinverse solution of $(A+B)x=v$ when $A$ is singluar and symmetric and $B$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Given $A$ a singular and symmetric matrix,  and $B$ a symmetric matrix, I find that solving $(A+B)x=v$ by
$$
x= (A+B)^+v
$$
gives the correct solution to my physical system. The physical system

1) actually has one unique solution.

2) satisfies $Ax=0$ and $Bx=v$

3) $A$'s rank +  $B$'s rank = $A$'s number of row (and column).

4) $A+B$ is singular.

example:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2&   1 & -1 &  0 & -1 \\
1 & -2   & -1 &  -1 & 0  \\
-1&  -1  & -2 &   -1 &  -1  \\
0 &  -1   &  -1 &  -2 & 1 \\
-1& 0   & -1 &   1& -2  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
4&   0 & -2 &  0 & 0\\
0& 0   & 0 &  0 & 0  \\
-2&  0  & 2 &   0 &  -3  \\
0 &  0   &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
0& 0   & -3 &   0& 9  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

where $A$ is rank 3 and $B$ is rank 2.  If adding $B$'s rows to A, then the matrix rank is 5. So I guess this linear system has indeed one unique solution.

$v=(66,0,11,0,-132)$. The solution is known a prior $x=(16,16,-1,-15,-15)$.

But why pseudoinverse gives the correct solution ? I looked through the wiki page on Moore-Penrose inverse in vain.

Comment: "actually has a unique solution" is a physical statement about the system that you're modeling rather than a mathematical statement about the system of equations.  If $A+B$ is singular and $x$ is a solution to $(A+B)x=v$, then there are infinitely many solutions to the linear system of equations- that's a mathematical fact.  What's missing here is some additional modeling assumption that might make the pseudoinverse solution the right solution.  Unfortunately, the context for this is not provided in your question.

Comment: Please provide more context- where does this system of equations come from?  How do you know that the pseuodinverse solution is the "right" solution? It may be relevant that a mathematical property of the pseudoinverse solution is that it is the minimum norm solution to the linear system of equations.

Comment: It is tedious to fully explain the context, however, I give an example of A and B. I know the solution is correct because the problem is given with ground truth.

Comment: Your example doesn’t fix the problem with the question.

Comment: Your example is missing $v$.

Comment: In the example A is rank 3 and B is rank 2, does this explain something?

Comment: Your example matrix $A+B$ is non-singular and thus $(A+B)x=v$ has a unique solution,   This isn't the situation you described in your question.

Comment: If $A, B \in R^{N\times N}$, All rows from $A$ and all rows from $B$ make a $2N\times N$ matrix whose rank is $N$, which probably implies that $(A+B)$ 's rank is also $N$.